# How to get an upload progress bar for urllib2?

Tags: python

I currently use the following code to **upload** one file to a remote server:

```
import MultipartPostHandler, urllib2, sys
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
params = {"data" : open("foo.bar") }
request=opener.open("http://127.0.0.1/api.php", params)
response = request.read()
```

This works fine, but for larger files the upload takes some time, and it would be nice to have a callback that allows me to display the upload progress?

I already tried the kodakloader solution, but it does not has a callback for a single file.

Does anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible to know upload progress with urllib2. I'm looking into using pycurl.

Comment: It looks like this solves my problem: http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/callbacks.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet from our python dependency script that [Chris Phillips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203002/chris-phillips) and I worked on @ [Cogi](http://www.cogi.com) (though he did this particular portion of it).  Complete script is [here](http://bitbucket.org/chphilli/scripts_from_cogi/src/tip/cogi/setupPython/installPythonDependencies.py).

```
    try:
        tmpfilehandle, tmpfilename = tempfile.mkstemp()
        with os.fdopen(tmpfilehandle, 'w+b') as tmpfile:
            print '  Downloading from %s' % self.alternateUrl

            self.progressLine = ''
            def showProgress(bytesSoFar, totalBytes):
                if self.progressLine:
                    sys.stdout.write('\b' * len(self.progressLine))

                self.progressLine = '    %s/%s (%0.2f%%)' % (bytesSoFar, totalBytes, float(bytesSoFar) / totalBytes * 100)
                sys.stdout.write(self.progressLine)

            urlfile = urllib2.urlopen(self.alternateUrl)
            totalBytes = int(urlfile.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip())
            bytesSoFar = 0

            showProgress(bytesSoFar, totalBytes)

            while True:
                readBytes = urlfile.read(1024 * 100)
                bytesSoFar += len(readBytes)

                if not readBytes:
                    break

                tmpfile.write(readBytes)
                showProgress(bytesSoFar, totalBytes)

    except HTTPError, e:
        sys.stderr.write('Unable to fetch URL: %s\n' % self.alternateUrl)
        raise
```

Comment: this shows progress of a download, correct? The question asks for a progress bar for an upload...